# Get request error Springboot to Zillow Api

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, zillow

I'm trying to do a get request from Springboot to Zillow API but I'm getting an error below:

Error: no exact match found for input address
`508`

and this is my code

```
public String getZillow()
{
    final String uri = 
            "https://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetSearchResults.htm&address=1756+Bluebird+Ct&citystatezip=Carrollton%2C+TX";
     
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
     
    System.out.println(result);
    return result;              
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/zillow", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAllEmployeesXML() 
{
    return getZillow();
}
```

I was able to see the xml object successfully with the uri address on the browser but not on Springboot.

Comment: the uri you posted is redirecting to main page can you post valid uri

Comment: Not sure is it safe to post my Zillow user key here that why I removed it.

Comment: "https://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetSearchResults.htm?zws-id=<YOUR_ZILLOW_KEY>&address=1756+Bluebird+Ct&citystatezip=Carrollton%2C+TX". Replace <YOUR_ZILLOW_KEY> with your key.